# First column in my imported .csv in R starts with 0 and I want to change that

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have imported a .csv into RStudio like many times before, but the first column that is called x1 - that refers to question number, starts with 0 and since there isn't a question number 0.

I would like to change it so 0-29 turns 1-30 (i.e. adding 1 to all the values of the first column).

What would be the way to do this?

**^** I believe that this is a very basic question, so basic that I can't seem to find the answer to it so with the risk of making a fool out of myself.

Comment: `df1[,1] <- df1[,1] + 1` ?

Comment: Thank you! The linked question didn't help me but this did.